# Android Studio не может сконвертировать Java -> Kotlin

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

При попытке преобразовать файл Java в файл Kotlin, Android Studio запускает процесс, после чего он неожиданно завершается, не дойдя до фазы 2. Исходник, с которым наблюдается проблема: https://github.com/drygdryg/WiFiPasswordSearcher/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/WiFiPasswordSearcher/MyActivity.java

Фрагмент журнала Android Studio ([idea.log](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/MM2CGjy2RR/)):

```
2020-03-27 09:56:34,871 [  86148]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - lateinit property target has not been initialized 
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property target has not been initialized
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.symbols.JKUniverseClassSymbol.getTarget(JKClassSymbol.kt:18)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.symbols.JKUniverseClassSymbol.getTarget(JKClassSymbol.kt:17)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.symbols.JKUniverseSymbol$DefaultImpls.getDeclaredIn(JKSymbol.kt:51)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.symbols.JKUniverseClassSymbol.getDeclaredIn(JKClassSymbol.kt:17)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.symbols.JKUniverseSymbol$DefaultImpls.getFqName(JKSymbol.kt:38)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.symbols.JKUniverseClassSymbol.getFqName(JKClassSymbol.kt:17)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.types.TypesUtilsKt.asPrimitiveType(typesUtils.kt:136)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.ImplicitCastsConversion.castToAsPrimitiveTypes(ImplicitCastsConversion.kt:120)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.ImplicitCastsConversion.castTo(ImplicitCastsConversion.kt:156)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.ImplicitCastsConversion.castTo$default(ImplicitCastsConversion.kt:153)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.ImplicitCastsConversion.convertMethodCallExpression(ImplicitCastsConversion.kt:86)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.ImplicitCastsConversion.applyToElement(ImplicitCastsConversion.kt:23)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.RecursiveApplicableConversionBase$recurse$1.invoke(RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.RecursiveApplicableConversionBase$recurse$1.invoke(RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.kt:12)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion$applyRecursive$2.invoke(MatchBasedConversion.kt:18)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion$applyRecursive$2.invoke(MatchBasedConversion.kt:13)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.tree.TreeUtilsKt.applyRecursive(treeUtils.kt:84)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion.applyRecursive(MatchBasedConversion.kt:15)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion.applyRecursive(MatchBasedConversion.kt:18)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.recurse(RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.ImplicitCastsConversion.applyToElement(ImplicitCastsConversion.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.RecursiveApplicableConversionBase$recurse$1.invoke(RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.RecursiveApplicableConversionBase$recurse$1.invoke(RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.kt:12)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion$applyRecursive$2.invoke(MatchBasedConversion.kt:18)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion$applyRecursive$2.invoke(MatchBasedConversion.kt:13)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.tree.TreeUtilsKt$applyRecursive$1.invoke(treeUtils.kt:62)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.tree.TreeUtilsKt.applyRecursive(treeUtils.kt:82)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion.applyRecursive(MatchBasedConversion.kt:15)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion.applyRecursive(MatchBasedConversion.kt:18)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.recurse(RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.ImplicitCastsConversion.applyToElement(ImplicitCastsConversion.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.RecursiveApplicableConversionBase$recurse$1.invoke(RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.RecursiveApplicableConversionBase$recurse$1.invoke(RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.kt:12)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion$applyRecursive$2.invoke(MatchBasedConversion.kt:18)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion$applyRecursive$2.invoke(MatchBasedConversion.kt:13)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.tree.TreeUtilsKt.applyRecursive(treeUtils.kt:84)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion.applyRecursive(MatchBasedConversion.kt:15)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion.applyRecursive(MatchBasedConversion.kt:18)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.recurse(RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.ImplicitCastsConversion.applyToElement(ImplicitCastsConversion.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.RecursiveApplicableConversionBase$recurse$1.invoke(RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.RecursiveApplicableConversionBase$recurse$1.invoke(RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.kt:12)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion$applyRecursive$2.invoke(MatchBasedConversion.kt:18)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion$applyRecursive$2.invoke(MatchBasedConversion.kt:13)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.tree.TreeUtilsKt$applyRecursive$1.invoke(treeUtils.kt:62)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.tree.TreeUtilsKt.applyRecursive(treeUtils.kt:82)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion.applyRecursive(MatchBasedConversion.kt:15)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion.applyRecursive(MatchBasedConversion.kt:18)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.recurse(RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.ImplicitCastsConversion.applyToElement(ImplicitCastsConversion.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.RecursiveApplicableConversionBase$recurse$1.invoke(RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.RecursiveApplicableConversionBase$recurse$1.invoke(RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.kt:12)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion$applyRecursive$2.invoke(MatchBasedConversion.kt:18)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion$applyRecursive$2.invoke(MatchBasedConversion.kt:13)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.tree.TreeUtilsKt.applyRecursive(treeUtils.kt:84)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion.applyRecursive(MatchBasedConversion.kt:15)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion.applyRecursive(MatchBasedConversion.kt:18)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.recurse(RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.ImplicitCastsConversion.applyToElement(ImplicitCastsConversion.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.RecursiveApplicableConversionBase$recurse$1.invoke(RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.RecursiveApplicableConversionBase$recurse$1.invoke(RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.kt:12)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion$applyRecursive$2.invoke(MatchBasedConversion.kt:18)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion$applyRecursive$2.invoke(MatchBasedConversion.kt:13)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.tree.TreeUtilsKt.applyRecursive(treeUtils.kt:84)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion.applyRecursive(MatchBasedConversion.kt:15)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion.applyRecursive(MatchBasedConversion.kt:18)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.recurse(RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.ImplicitCastsConversion.applyToElement(ImplicitCastsConversion.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.RecursiveApplicableConversionBase$recurse$1.invoke(RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.RecursiveApplicableConversionBase$recurse$1.invoke(RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.kt:12)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion$applyRecursive$2.invoke(MatchBasedConversion.kt:18)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion$applyRecursive$2.invoke(MatchBasedConversion.kt:13)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.tree.TreeUtilsKt$applyRecursive$1.invoke(treeUtils.kt:62)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.tree.TreeUtilsKt.applyRecursive(treeUtils.kt:82)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion.applyRecursive(MatchBasedConversion.kt:15)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion.applyRecursive(MatchBasedConversion.kt:18)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.recurse(RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.ImplicitCastsConversion.applyToElement(ImplicitCastsConversion.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.RecursiveApplicableConversionBase$recurse$1.invoke(RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.RecursiveApplicableConversionBase$recurse$1.invoke(RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.kt:12)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion$applyRecursive$2.invoke(MatchBasedConversion.kt:18)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion$applyRecursive$2.invoke(MatchBasedConversion.kt:13)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.tree.TreeUtilsKt.applyRecursive(treeUtils.kt:84)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion.applyRecursive(MatchBasedConversion.kt:15)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion.applyRecursive(MatchBasedConversion.kt:18)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.recurse(RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.ImplicitCastsConversion.applyToElement(ImplicitCastsConversion.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.RecursiveApplicableConversionBase$recurse$1.invoke(RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.RecursiveApplicableConversionBase$recurse$1.invoke(RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.kt:12)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion$applyRecursive$2.invoke(MatchBasedConversion.kt:18)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion$applyRecursive$2.invoke(MatchBasedConversion.kt:13)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.tree.TreeUtilsKt$applyRecursive$1.invoke(treeUtils.kt:62)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.tree.TreeUtilsKt.applyRecursive(treeUtils.kt:82)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion.applyRecursive(MatchBasedConversion.kt:15)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion.applyRecursive(MatchBasedConversion.kt:18)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.recurse(RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.ImplicitCastsConversion.applyToElement(ImplicitCastsConversion.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.RecursiveApplicableConversionBase$recurse$1.invoke(RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.RecursiveApplicableConversionBase$recurse$1.invoke(RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.kt:12)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion$applyRecursive$2.invoke(MatchBasedConversion.kt:18)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion$applyRecursive$2.invoke(MatchBasedConversion.kt:13)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.tree.TreeUtilsKt.applyRecursive(treeUtils.kt:84)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion.applyRecursive(MatchBasedConversion.kt:15)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion.applyRecursive(MatchBasedConversion.kt:18)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.recurse(RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.ImplicitCastsConversion.applyToElement(ImplicitCastsConversion.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.RecursiveApplicableConversionBase$recurse$1.invoke(RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.RecursiveApplicableConversionBase$recurse$1.invoke(RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.kt:12)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion$applyRecursive$2.invoke(MatchBasedConversion.kt:18)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion$applyRecursive$2.invoke(MatchBasedConversion.kt:13)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.tree.TreeUtilsKt$applyRecursive$1.invoke(treeUtils.kt:62)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.tree.TreeUtilsKt.applyRecursive(treeUtils.kt:82)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion.applyRecursive(MatchBasedConversion.kt:15)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion.applyRecursive(MatchBasedConversion.kt:18)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.recurse(RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.ImplicitCastsConversion.applyToElement(ImplicitCastsConversion.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.RecursiveApplicableConversionBase$recurse$1.invoke(RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.RecursiveApplicableConversionBase$recurse$1.invoke(RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.kt:12)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion$applyRecursive$2.invoke(MatchBasedConversion.kt:18)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion$applyRecursive$2.invoke(MatchBasedConversion.kt:13)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.tree.TreeUtilsKt.applyRecursive(treeUtils.kt:84)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion.applyRecursive(MatchBasedConversion.kt:15)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion.applyRecursive(MatchBasedConversion.kt:18)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.recurse(RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.ImplicitCastsConversion.applyToElement(ImplicitCastsConversion.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.runConversion(RecursiveApplicableConversionBase.kt:18)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.SequentialBaseConversion$runConversion$1.invoke(BaseConversion.kt:28)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.SequentialBaseConversion$runConversion$1.invoke(BaseConversion.kt:24)
    at kotlin.sequences.TransformingSequence$iterator$1.next(Sequences.kt:172)
    at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.max(_Sequences.kt:1149)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.SequentialBaseConversion$DefaultImpls.runConversion(BaseConversion.kt:28)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.conversions.MatchBasedConversion.runConversion(MatchBasedConversion.kt:13)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.ConversionsRunner.doApply(ConversionsRunner.kt:89)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.NewJavaToKotlinConverter.elementsToKotlin(NewJavaToKotlinConverter.kt:166)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.NewJavaToKotlinConverter$filesToKotlin$1$1.compute(NewJavaToKotlinConverter.kt:65)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.NewJavaToKotlinConverter$filesToKotlin$1$1.compute(NewJavaToKotlinConverter.kt:42)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:922)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.NewJavaToKotlinConverter$filesToKotlin$1.invoke(NewJavaToKotlinConverter.kt:64)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.NewJavaToKotlinConverter$filesToKotlin$1.invoke(NewJavaToKotlinConverter.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.NewJ2kWithProgressProcessor$process$1.run(NewJavaToKotlinConverter.kt:228)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:169)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:544)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:156)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.NewJ2kWithProgressProcessor.process(NewJavaToKotlinConverter.kt:228)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.nj2k.NewJavaToKotlinConverter.filesToKotlin(NewJavaToKotlinConverter.kt:62)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.actions.JavaToKotlinAction$Companion$convertFiles$1.invoke(JavaToKotlinAction.kt:138)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.actions.JavaToKotlinAction$Companion$convertFiles$2.invoke(JavaToKotlinAction.kt:148)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.actions.JavaToKotlinAction$Companion$convertFiles$3.invoke(JavaToKotlinAction.kt:162)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.actions.JavaToKotlinAction$Companion$convertFiles$3.invoke(JavaToKotlinAction.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.actions.JavaToKotlinActionKt$sam$java_lang_Runnable$0.run(JavaToKotlinAction.kt)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:253)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:894)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$5.run(CoreProgressManager.java:447)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:169)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:591)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:537)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:156)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$null$9(ApplicationImpl.java:552)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Дополнительная информация:
Android Studio: 3.6.1

Comment: добавьте код вашего класса в вопрос, по ссылкам здесь никто рыскать не будет, логи тоже приложите в тело вопроса, но не всю кучу, а только то что считаете нужным.

Comment: Код сложный, вот и не справился конвертер. Бывает. Сюда лучше обратитесь https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT

Comment: редкостный г-год

Comment: @keekkenen он написан не мною. Моя цель — перевести его на Kotlin и отрефакторить.

Comment: тогда стоит идти в обратном порядке - рефакторить и конвертировать